# Why is the Pytorch Dropout layer affecting all values, not only the ones set to zero?

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor, dropout

The dropout layer from Pytorch changes the values that are not set to zero. Using Pytorch's documentation example: ([source](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.Dropout)):

```py
import torch
import torch.nn  as nn

m = nn.Dropout(p=0.5)
input = torch.ones(5, 5)
```

```py
print(input)
tensor([[1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., 1., 1.]])
```

Then I pass it through a `dropout` layer:

```py
output = m(input)
print(output)
tensor([[0., 0., 2., 2., 0.],
        [2., 0., 2., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 2.],
        [2., 2., 2., 2., 2.],
        [2., 0., 0., 0., 2.]])
```

The values that aren't set to zero are now 2. Why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is how the dropout regularization works. After a dropout the values are divided by the keeping probability (in this case 0.5).

Since PyTorch Dropout function receives the probability of zeroing a neuron as input, if you use `nn.Dropout(p=0.2)` that means it has 0.8 chance of keeping. so the values on the table will be 1/(1-0.2).

This is called "inverted dropout technique" and it is done in order to ensure that the expected value of the activation remains the same.

Comment: Close but not quite. with `p=0.2` it gives `1/(1-0.2)`, so `1.25`. For it to be 5, it's `p=0.8`.

Comment: ops, That is because pytorch uses probability to 0 instead of keeping, I will edit.