# Question About Dropout Layer and Batch Normalization Layer in DNN model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have some queries about the Dropout layer and Batch normalized layer. Basically, I have made a simple DNN structure with a Dropout layer and Batch normalized layer and train it that's fine.

The simple structure of DNN model for example:

```
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

model = keras.Sequential([
    layers.Dense(10, activation='relu', input_shape=[11]),
    layers.Dropout(0.3),
    layers.BatchNormalization(),
    layers.Dense(8, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dropout(0.3),
    layers.BatchNormalization(),
    layers.Dense(6, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dropout(0.3),
    layers.BatchNormalization(),
    layers.Dense(1,activation='softmax'),
])

model.compile(
    optimizer='adam',
    loss='mae',
)

history = model.fit(
    X_train, y_train,
    validation_data=(X_valid, y_valid),
    batch_size=256,
    epochs=100,
    verbose=0,
)
```

But now I would like to use the train model's weights and bias of all layers in my custom prediction model(forget about the other way).

```
# Predictions for test
test_logits_1 = tf.matmul(tf_test_dataset, weights_1) + biases_1
test_relu_1 = tf.nn.relu(test_logits_1)

test_logits_2 = tf.matmul(test_relu_1, weights_2) + biases_2
test_relu_2 = tf.nn.relu(test_logits_2)

test_logits_3 = tf.matmul(test_relu_2, weights_3) + biases_3
test_relu_3 = tf.nn.relu(test_logits_3)

test_logits_4 = tf.matmul(test_logits_3 , weights_4) + biases_4
test_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(test_relu_4)
```

Now the question is here: have to need to add the dropout layer and batch normalized layer, batch size in the prediction model?? If yes then why to do that and how do I extract all the details of layers and use them in my custom prediction model?

Comment: You do not need to add a dropout layer as dropout layer is [meant](https://keras.io/api/layers/regularization_layers/dropout/) to function only during training and not during inference. The batch normalization needs to be added I believe, you can get the formula easily from [here](https://keras.io/api/layers/normalization_layers/batch_normalization/)

Comment: Can explain why it needs in the prediction time and which parameters should I take  ??

Comment: You absolutely need to use the dropout layer. During training, the dropout layer multiplies all the remaining values by `1/(1-p)` otherwise the network will receive double the input it's used to when testing. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59003985/why-is-the-pytorch-dropout-layer-affecting-all-values-not-only-the-ones-set-to0

Comment: @Nicolas Gervais i know that dropout layer regularises the rest of the values which are not set to zero, but isn't the OP here asking about just using trained weights for inferencing?

Comment: The batch normalization layer doesn't have any parameters, it is just a normalization process(i.e. just some data manipulation), similar to a how a softmax layer doesn't have any parameters.

Comment: yes he is, never mind

Comment: @sai BatchNorm does have parameters (the normalization weights), so you are completely incorrect here.

Comment: Basically, My question is that I want to use my whole training model structure ( with bias weights and other parameters) in my custom prediction model so in this context what should we need to do and what we can skip??

Comment: @ Dr. Snoopy How do I get the details of the parameters and use them in a custom prediction model. Can you code it??

Comment: @BijoyGayen I don't know what are your scope, but u can consider tf.nn.batch_normalization and tf.nn.dropout

Comment: @ Marco Cerliani, I know can add the command (tf.nn.batch_normalized,tf.nn.dropout). But my question is during the prediction time how the dropout layer and batch normalized layer help,  if I add two layers?

Answer (score 0):

@Dr. Snoopy thanks for pointing out that the BatchNormalization has parameters but to my knowledge they are not the normalization weights(weights being normalized) based on what I was able to deduce from the docs and little research.

The [doc](https://keras.io/api/layers/normalization_layers/batch_normalization/) says the following(quoted text below) and based on the description it is clear that **beta** and **gamma** values are trainable variables which tallies with the output from tensorflow.

> During training (i.e. when using fit() or when calling the layer/model with the argument training=True), the layer normalizes its output using the mean and standard deviation of the current batch of inputs. That is to say, for each channel being normalized, the layer returns (batch - mean(batch)) / (var(batch) + epsilon) * gamma + beta, where:
>
> - epsilon is small constant (configurable as part of the constructor arguments)
> - gamma is a learned scaling factor (initialized as 1), which can be disabled by passing scale=False to the constructor.
> - beta is a learned offset factor (initialized as 0), which can be disabled by passing center=False to the constructor.

[image]

But that is not the end of the story as the model summary indicates more parameters than the number of parameters **beta** and **gamma** comprise of.

[image]

A factor of **4** can be observed here i.e. the number of parameters in a BatchNormalization layer are 4 times the input shape the layer operates on.

These additional parameters are *moving_mean* and *moving_variance* values which can be seen in the following output

[image]

Coming back to the original question and concern of OP, "What parameters should i worry about?", the parameters that are needed for **inference** are *moving_mean*, *moving_variance*, *beta*, and *gamma* values.

The way to use these values/parameters is again easily deducible from the docs which I quote here again-

> During inference (i.e. when using evaluate() or predict() or when calling the layer/model with the argument training=False (which is the default), the layer normalizes its output using a moving average of the mean and standard deviation of the batches it has seen during training. That is to say, it returns (batch - self.moving_mean) / (self.moving_var + epsilon) * gamma + beta.
>
> self.moving_mean and self.moving_var are non-trainable variables that are updated each time the layer in called in training mode, as such:
>
> - moving_mean = moving_mean * momentum + mean(batch) * (1 - momentum)
> - moving_var = moving_var * momentum + var(batch) * (1 - momentum)
>
> As such, the layer will only normalize its inputs during inference after having been trained on data that has similar statistics as the inference data.

So assuming the *moving_mean*, *moving_variance*, *beta*, and *gamma* values are available for every BatchNormalization layer, I think the following piece of code needs to be added after the first activation-

```py
# epsilon is just to avoid ZeroDivisionError, so the default value should be okay
test_BN_1 = (test_relu_1 - moving_mean_1) / (moving_var_1 + epsilon_1) * gamma_1 + beta_1
```

---

EDIT:

Turns out that the documentation seems to be wrong but the implementation seems to be right based on what I could deduce from the source code on github.

If you follow the following links you'll see that the in `call` method of `BatchNormalization` class here https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/normalization.py#L1227 the calculation is actually done by keras backend normalization function `batch_normalization` here https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/35146d00b44ca645fbf4ad0b007faa07632c6f9e/keras/backend.py#L2963. The backend function doc string seems to be in agreement with what is mentioned in the reference paper and the picture you've posted.

So that means, you should use the square root of the variance only.

Comment: Yes, we need to use mini-batch statistics during inference as in the implementations you mentioned. In the original equation, they use the square root of variance pulse epsilon. But Keras package avoids the square root variance pulse epsilon. Which equation should take?

Comment: Could you refer me to which "original equation" you are talking about?

Comment: please check this equation: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BiPHy.png